The definition of Hastings and Haah honeycomb code
In the original paper of the honeycomb code, the edges are classified by the numbers 0, 1, 2 based on which faces they are connected to, and the types of Pauli of each edge are defined based on the directions. Then, at each round, one of the three types (0, 1, 2) of edges are measured. Thus, at each round, X, Y, and Z type 2-body checks belonging to type 0 are measured simultaneously.
However, in some papers, for example, by Craig Gidney et al., it seems that type 0 edges are Pauli X operators, type 1 edges are Pauli Y operators, and type 2 edges are Pauli Z operators, and only one type of Pauli operators are measured at a certain round.
So, the definitions of 2-body checks and measurement sequence in the original paper and the paper by Craig Gidney et al. seem different.
Are these two honeycomb code different in definition, or am I misunderstanding something?

They are the same, up to single qubit basis rotations. If you compile them both into $M_{ZZ}$ + single qubit gates then you will get identical circuits.
It's the same distinction as the CSS surface code vs the XZZX surface code. The difference can matter in some cases, like if you have multiple two qubit interactions and are trying to do something like preserve a noise bias, but is otherwise irrelevant.
The reason we tweaked the definition is because it made edge measurement round correspond to edge basis. We considered this definition to be much simpler. It avoided the need to separately annotate the edge types by direction and number the hexagons; the type of the edge just becomes the hex type it spans between. It also makes the entire support of the observables be in a single basis each round.

